# Can't create a calendar from a list in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Have had a list that has been created using external content (i.e. Imported from an Oracle Database).  This was created for me by another developer.  Inside this list we have a series of columns that have datetimes, person names, descriptions ect.

How can I use this list to populate a calendar?  I have read that you can create a calendar view from it by clicking "Create View" but I only see the options for "Standard View" and "Access View".  Does this mean that the list is required to be in a certain format before the option will appear? or do I have to have SharePoint Designer?

Thanks
James